# Cartier divisor $\mathbb{Q}$-trivial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective variety and $D$ a Cartier divisor on $X$ so that $D\sim_\mathbb{Q} 0$. Is it true that $D$ is itself linearly equivalent to zero?

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick tour of the site (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most of your time here.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the notion of Q rational Cartier divisors, but it seems like a nontrivial Cartier divisor D which is torsion in the Cartier class group should provide a counterexample, right?